# How to implement this logic in grafana dashboard?

Tags: grafana, wonderware

I pulled 3 time series signals A, B, and C from a SQL server data source. I want to implement the following logic:

```
if A > 0: 
    if B > C:
        Status = 1
    else:
        Status = 0
else Status = 0
```

What is the best way to implement this logic in Grafana? I tried Transform in Grafana and it is possible there to subtract B and C there but I need to implement the comparison.
Thank you for your help.

Edit: The query is a bit complex because A, B, and C are queried from the Wonderware historian table. That's why I want to query each tag separately in Grafana and realize the logic there.

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(mi,-5,GetDate())
SET @EndDate = GetDate()
SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT  TagName, Value
FROM (
    SELECT History.TagName, DateTime, Value, vValue, StartDateTime
    FROM History
    WHERE History.TagName IN ('A')
    AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'
    AND wwCycleCount = 100
    AND wwVersion = 'Latest'
    AND DateTime >= @StartDate
    AND DateTime <= @EndDate) temp 
WHERE temp.StartDateTime >= @StartDate
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is now way to actually compare something in Grafana. But you can apply a value mapping, that will map positive and negative values differently.

Comment: Yet the easiest way will be to apply your logic on the query level, ans simply return what you need straight from DB.

Comment: I mean regardless of the source data, as long as all three are returned from the same data source, you can wrap them into one more outer select and apply your logical expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I know nothing of grafana but I took your description and query to come up with this which runs on my historian. Mod to fit your needs I guess?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(mi,-5,GetDate())
SET @EndDate = GetDate()

SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT  QueryDate,
        'AValue' = [A],
        'BValue' = [B],
        'CValue' = [C],
        'Status' = IIF( [A] > 0 AND [B] > [C], 1, 0)
FROM (
    SELECT 'QueryDate' = [DateTime],
            Tagname,
            Value
    FROM (
        SELECT [DateTime],Tagname,Value
        FROM History
        WHERE History.TagName IN ('A','B','C')
        AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'
        AND wwCycleCount = 100
        AND wwVersion = 'Latest'
        AND DateTime >= @StartDate
        AND DateTime <= @EndDate
    ) HistoricalData
) As DataValues
PIVOT (
    MAX(Value) FOR Tagname IN ([A],[B],[C])
) As PivotData
```

Comment: At the end, I wrote a similar query and pulled the data from the live table and it worked. I I accepted the answer, so it helps other to find the alternative way if they look for doing such aggregation in Grafana.